# Has the Asshai'i language ever been created?

Tags: history, conlang-learning, song-of-ice-and-fire

[I heard that David Peterson thought about creating the Asshai'i language.](https://dedalvs.tumblr.com/post/83023381739/could-you-write-something-in-asshaii-please-any)

Did that ever happen? Has the Asshai'i language ever been actually created?

Comment: All information I could find on this was that there has been a sketch, but no full-blown description of it.

Comment: Probably better to ask if any resources on it were ever published.